# golang flag stops parsing after the first non-option

Tags: go, flags, command-line-interface

i am building a little cli tool that boots my app in development or production.

the way i want it to work is like this:

```
app run --dev or app run --prod
```

Atm it doest parses the flags after my command but only before my command. So this works

```
app --dev run or app --prod run
```

Any idee how to fix it this so i can use it after my command? here is my code

```
func main() {
    //flag.Usage := usage
    flag.Parse()
    args := flag.Args()
    if len(args) == 0 {
        Usage()
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    if *dev {
        os.Setenv("ENV", "development")
    }

    if *prod {
        os.Setenv("ENV", "production")
    }

    switch {
    // Run
    case args[0] == "run" && len(args) == 1:
        os.Setenv("port", *port)
        log.Printf("Booting in %s", os.Getenv("ENV"))
        Run()

    // Help
    case args[0] == "help" && len(args) == 1:
        Usage()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just call `ENV=dev yourapp run` - which avoids the weird SetEnv dance you have going and just sets it directly (and only for that run).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Traditionally, the UNIX option parser `getopt()` stops parsing after the first non-option. The glibc altered this behavior to support options in arbitrary positions, a controversial decision. The `flag` package implements the traditional behavior.

One thing you could do is permuting the arguments array before parsing the flags. That's what the glibc does:

```
func permutateArgs(args []string) int {
    args = args[1:]
    optind := 0

    for i := range args {
        if args[i][0] == '-' {
            tmp := args[i]
            args[i] = args[optind]
            args[optind] = tmp
            optind++
        }
    }

    return optind + 1
}
```

This code permutates `args` such that options are in front, leaving the program name untouched. `permutateArgs` returns the index of the first non-option after permutation. Use this code like this:

```
optind := permutateArgs(os.Args)
flags.Parse()

// process non-options
for i := range os.Args[optind:] {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @AnthonyDeMeulemeester Please try again. The code should work now.

Comment: this is an awesome answer -- although it does not preserve the ordering of non flag arguments. for instance, given the args ```a -x b c -y```, you get `-x -y b c a` instead of `-x -y a b c`. A solution that preserves ordering would be great!

Comment: Also works only for the Bool flags. For flags that take values, like `-o result.txt`, this method will treat 'result.txt' as an argument and not as an option flag.

Comment: @CodeExpress Yes, indeed. It shouldn't be too difficult to adapt the code to also consider other kinds of options.

Comment: Thank you. You can also more easily process the non-options with `flag.Args()`

Answer (score 1):

This is simply the way the flag package deals with arguments. Argument handling is always somewhat convention driven, and the flag package definitely does not follow the gnu-style that many are accustomed to.

One way is to sort the options before the commands:

```
// example argument sorting using sort.Stable
type ArgSlice []string

func (p ArgSlice) Len() int      { return len(p) }
func (p ArgSlice) Swap(i, j int) { p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i] }

func (p ArgSlice) Less(i, j int) bool {
    if len(p[i]) == 0 {
        return false
    }
    if len(p[j]) == 0 {
        return true
    }
    return p[i][0] == '-' && p[j][0] != '-'
}

func main() {

    args := []string{"cmd", "-a", "arg", "-b", "-c"}
    sort.Stable(ArgSlice(args))
    // if sorting os.Args, make sure to omit the first argument
    // sort.Stable(ArgSlice(os.Args[1:]))

    fmt.Println(args)
}
```

Many packages use separate FlagSets for subcommands, which provides nice separation, but this would not work when there are possibly different flags between subcommands. The only solution there is to duplicate the flags across each level.

However, the best answer is still to follow the conventions used by the flag package, and not try to fight it.