# Golang flag package stops parsing when encountering a non-flag

Tags: go, go-flag

The built-in `flags` package seems to break parsing upon encountering the first non-flag argument for a process. Consider this application:

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    alpha := flag.String("alpha", "", "the first")
    beta := flag.String("beta", "", "the second")
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println("ALPHA: " + *alpha)
    fmt.Println("BETA: " + *beta)
}
```

The output of three different invocations where a "subcommand" is provided then look like this:

```
$ ./app --alpha 1 --beta 2 hi
ALPHA: 1
BETA: 2
$ ./app --alpha 1 hi --beta 2 
ALPHA: 1
BETA: 
$ ./app hi --alpha 1 --beta 2 
ALPHA: 
BETA:
```

How can a subcommand followed by a flag such as `git status --short` be recreated using the `flags` package?

Comment: You need to write some code. Package `flag` is not comprehensive. Many people for this reason use some 3rd party package for their cli programs, rather than the stdlib `flag` package.

Comment: For example you can take `os.Args`, take the command and subcommands from the left side, and then pass the rest to `fs.Parse` where `fs` is the instance of `flag.FlagSet` which you used to specify the flags.

Comment: You can also take a look at [`cmd/go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/main.go) to see how the Go team implements the `go` tool (the subcommands are in the `cmd/go/internal/` directory).

Comment: Example: https://gobyexample.com/command-line-subcommands

Comment: I ultimately went with the following Go package as it allowed for flexibility with `app cmd --flag` and `app --flag cmd`. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/DavidGamba/go-getoptions

Answer (score 4):

I faced this same issue once, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113313/golang-flag-stops-parsing-after-the-first-non-option) helped me.

Basically, go `flag` package uses the UNIX option parser `getopt()` that stops parsing after the first non-option.

You can find the solution in the above link as well.